# Destruction of local Static variable

Tags: c++, static, local, destructor

I have a function f() with two local static variables, one of them (t3) points to dynamically allocated memory and other is normal one t1 (which I think is allocated on stack.).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
   test(const char *name): _name(name)
    {
            cout << _name << " created" << endl;
    }
    ~test()
    {
            cout << _name << " destroyed" << endl;
    }
    string _name;
    static test tc; // static member
 };
test test::tc(".class static data member");

test gvar("..global non-static object ");
static test sgvar("...global static object");

void f()
{

    static int num = 10 ; // POD type, init before enter main function
    static  test tl("..Local static object on (stack???)");
    static  test* t3 = new test("..Local static object in  free store");
    test t2("...local non-static object.....");
    cout << "Function executed" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "----------------------Program start----------------------" << endl;
    test t("LocalToMain non-static object");

    f();

    cout << "----------------------Program end-------------------------" << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

I get the following output

```
# main                                                           
.class static data member created                                      
..global non-static object  created                                    
...global static object created                                        
----------------------Program start----------------------              
LocalToMain non-static object created                                  
..Local static object on stack created                                 
..Local static object in  free store created                           
...local non-static object..... created                                
Function executed                                                      
...local non-static object..... destroyed                              
----------------------Program end-------------------------             
LocalToMain non-static object destroyed                                
..Local static object on stack destroyed                               
...global static object destroyed                                      
..global non-static object  destroyed                                  
.class static data member destroyed
```

- My Question is

  1. Destructor of local static t1 is called, but destructor for local static t3 is not called.Why?
  2. What is the storage duration of t3 and t1?
  3. Is t1 stored on stack and t2 on heap ? if not where are they stored?

Comment: `t3` is a raw pointer to a `test` object - it's not a `test` object itself, so the destructor isn't automatically called.

Comment: ok, I agree static t3 is a name and is a pointer to a region of memory.How to call destructor and free the memory ? Is it a design flaw to construct static pointer pointing to heap object ?

Comment: Always use a "smart pointer" to manage the ownership of memory allocated by `new`. In this case `unique_ptr` would be a good choice: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the C++ specification doesn't actually say anything about where local (static or non-static) variables are stored, it's up to the compiler.

As for your questions, the variable `t3` *is* destructed, but it's the *pointer* that is destructed and not what it points to. As you don't `delete` the object you `new` it will not be destructed by the run-time, and the memory will "leak".

The life-time of both `t1` and `t3` is the life-time of the program.

And where `t1` is stored I don't know, probably in a special data segment loaded into memory, but `t2` is a normal local variable which most compilers store on the stack.

There's really not much difference between e.g. `num` and `t1`. A local static variable is like any other local static variable, no matter the type.

Comment: It would make sense if static local variables were destroyed after all static variables in file scope completed (since static file scope destructors could call functions with static local variables), but I don't know whether that is the case or not.